# Add "Open in desktop app" feature for Microsoft office document

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, desktop, collaboration

I want to add "open in desktop app" feature for Microsoft office document uploaded in my SaaS product. Is there a an API from Microsoft which allows me to achieve that seamlessly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. See [Office URI Schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes)

To open an Excel file you can do something like this:

`ms-excel:ofe|u|https://locationofthefile.com/file.xls`

Use `ofe` to open a file and edit or `ofv` to open a file and view.

There are more complex options as you can read in the docs. But this will probably do it for the most cases

| Application | URI |
| --- | --- |
| Word | ms-word: |
| Power Point | ms-powerpoint: |
| Visio | ms-visio: |
| Access | ms-access: |
| Project | ms-project: |
| Publisher | ms-publisher: |
| SharePoint | ms-spd: |
| Infopath | ms-infopath: |