# Office Scripts Open Excel file in Desktop

Tags: excel, scripting, desktop

Dears,
In Excel webapp, there is a menu button to open the Excel file in desktop app.
Can this action be done in Office Scripts? Open Excel file in Desktop?

main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {}

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644272/add-open-in-desktop-app-feature-for-microsoft-office-document/68298093#68298093) already. But for people landing on this page here it is.

---

See [Office URI Schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes)

To open an Excel file you can do something like this:

`ms-excel:ofe|u|https://locationofthefile.com/file.xls`

Use `ofe` to open a file and edit or `ofv` to open a file and view.

There are more complex options as you can read in the docs. But this will probably do it for the most cases

| Application | URI |
| --- | --- |
| Word | ms-word: |
| Power Point | ms-powerpoint: |
| Visio | ms-visio: |
| Access | ms-access: |
| Project | ms-project: |
| Publisher | ms-publisher: |
| SharePoint | ms-spd: |
| Infopath | ms-infopath: |